# Polynomial Hierarchy and its Relation to Multi-Phase/States Physical Systems

Tags: complexity-theory, computability

We know that at the end computation should be done by physical systems which follow laws of physics. I know there are some researches that study the [phase transition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_transition) phenomenon in physics and try to connect it with some properties in complexity theory (such as P and NP famous problem ). Just a quick review for example the phase transition happens from 2-SAT problem to 3-SAT problem. The first one is in P and the second one is NP-Complete.

My question is that: Is there any study that shows the **mapping of Polynomial Hierarchy** (PH) and **multi-phase systems**? Is there any mapping between PH-Complete problems and real physical system states? If so, are all levels of these hierarchy stable?

Comment: If there are PH-complete problems, then the polynomial hierarchy collapses.  Proof:  Consider a problem $P$ which is complete for PH.  Since $P \in $ PH, it appears in some level $\Sigma^p_k$.  Since any problem $Q \in $ PH reduces to $P$, it follows that $Q \in \Sigma^p_k$.

Comment: I forgot the conclusion.  Hence PH $ \subseteq \Sigma^p_k$.

Comment: @PålGD: we know that If the polynomial hierarchy has any complete problems, then it has only finitely many distinct levels. considering this fact are there any similar analogies in physical systems?